# How to return all the data using sequelize in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, sequelize.js

I tried to call a function internally while making an api call and to get data from DB and to fetch it as response using promise.

Like this:

```
'use strict';

const {
    User
  } = require("../../DBConnection/TimeDB");

function currentTime(address){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(address != null) {
            User.findAll({attributes: ['UTC offset'],
                where: {
                    Timezone: { $like: '%'+address+'%' }
                }
            }).then(TimeZoneData => {
                if(TimeZoneData.length != 0) {
                    var offset = parseInt(TimeZoneData[0].dataValues['UTC offset']),
                        d = new Date(),
                        utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000),
                        nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset)),
                        obj = {},
                        key = 'data';
                        obj[key] = [];
                        var data = {
                            Time: nd.toLocaleString,
                            location: address
                        };
                        obj[key].push(data);
                    resolve(obj);
                } 
            });
        } else {
            reject("No results found for this address: "+address);
        }
    });
};

exports.helper = currentTime
```

I need both time and location data in my response json. But it only return location. It won't return time. I dont know why. How to resolve it???

Comment: use nd.toLocaleString() instead of nd.toLocaleString

Comment: Sorry i already got it and changed it. That code works perfectly. Also Thanks for your comment also.